# Someone is requesting a certificate in order to communicate with my web service

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a simple web service. The server is a regular, public-facing HTTPS server with a valid SSL cert. The partner who will be using the service is telling me "I need to get you certificate" and "Oracle requires that we install in our cert wallet.". What exactly should i send them? I can access the web service myself from a web browser or with no problems without installing anything. Is this an oracle thing or something specific to the method by which they're accessing the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're being a little silly; they can get the information for themselves and check it against a public CA, assuming that's how you've set things up; they've probably just not checked whether this info is verifiable. (If it *wasn't* signed by a public CA, they'd be right to ask as there's just no way to be sure that you're not already being spoofed.) Still, there's no harm in giving the information out through other channels too.

What they want is the public part of the key pair (not the private part!) that is used to establish the server's identity for HTTPS. It's fine to hand that out; you could also have a copy of it printed in your local newspaper and that would not decrease your security at all. There's a fair chance you've got the information still from when you were setting the server up; it's the information that is returned to you from the certificate authority (usually in a PEM file). If not, you can extract the information from your server's keypair with `keytool`:

```
keytool -exportcert -rfc -file publickey.pem -keystore path/to/keystore -alias theAlias
```

There are many other [options to `keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) (e.g., for different formats of keystore) and you might need to experiment to get the right set.

Comment: i ended up doing more research and got the cert before i read this, but your reply is perfect. it summed it up nicely. thanks for your time.

Comment: i should mention, that to generate the PEM file, i used firefox and exported the certificate after going to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specifically mention the authentication mechanism that is in place.  My guess is that they expect to use a certificate to pass along with request to the service to authenticate their requests.  Oracle again is a broad term, not sure if this a specific system or ERP.  Either way it seems like they want you to issue them a certificate that can be used when calling against your web service.

If you use a simple service with basic authentication then you will have to communicate that to them.  If it has no authentication that's an entirely different response.  Worst case you may have to update your service to support certificate based authentication, in which case... have fun.

Comment: there is no authentication. they are passing a url and getting a simple text response.

Comment: OK, maybe they don't understand the authentication scheme, either way I'm not sure what all else they would need a certificate for.

Comment: i did some work with curl before and i know that if you try to retrieve an https page you will get an error unless you specify a parameter telling it to trust the cert (-k parameter?). anyway, i found this page that tells how to configure curl to trust the cert: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: @Don I'd bet they've not actually _tried_ doing it yet, and are instead bureaucratically waiting for something they don't actually need…

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. Either way it's something thats on them and the system they are using. And, it's all information they can easily get based on the URL you have provided to them. Again, sounds like they don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: @DonalFellows +1 damn right they are. If they have an Oracle system you can be sure that's the problem.

Comment: It sounds to me like they are receiving some programming error "Certificate required" and just asking me for what the programming language is telling them. in fact its a CA issued cert so they should have been able to get what they need. anyway, i sent them the PEM and it should be fine.